# Is there a way send ethernet packet directly on link using winsock on windows?

Tags: windows, winsock, ethernet, winsock2, raw-sockets

Is there a way send ethernet packet directly on link using winsock on windows?

I need to broadcast an ethernet packet on a link (i.e. Destination Mac-Address: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff))

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to directly access ethernet links.  That is a hardware layer that is protected by Windows.  To send data out on a specific ethernet adapter, you need to `bind()` a socket to that adapter's IP address, then you can `send()` or `sendto()` your data to a destination IP as needed.

To broadcast a packet, send the data to the bound adapter's subnet broadcast IP address, which you can calculate dynamically by using `GetAdaptersInfo()` or `GetIpAddrTable()` to retrieve the adapter's IP address and subnet mask and then OR/AND'ing them together:

```
BroadcastIP = (IPAddress & SubnetMask) | ~SubnetMask;
```